# Abort Trap 6 error installing PyMC on OSX 10.7

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, pymc

I built and installed PyMC from source. It's taken a lot of debugging, but after a long time I succeeded at installing it. However, now when I try to import it, it's giving me an `Abort Trap: 6` error.

```
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.1-2 (64-bit)

Python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.1-2 (64-bit)| (default, Jul 27 2011, 14:50:45) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "packages", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>> import pymc
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm using OSX 10.7, numpy 1.8.0, scipy 0.13.0, pandas 0.3.0, matplotlib 1.4.x, and trying to install PyMC 3.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that matplotlib was crashing when loading the font `/Library/Fonts/NISC18030.ttf`. Since the font is not necessary, I just moved it to my temp folder and it fixed the problem. No idea why matplotlib was having trouble with it.

Comment: Could you say how you determined that matplotlib was crashing on a particular font?